# SVGs doesn't render in any browser when hosted externally

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have the following allIcons.svg file hosted on external-domain and the definition of symbol id#icon-svg-cta looks something like this:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" height="0" style="position:absolute" width="0">

 <symbol id="my-svg-cta" viewBox="0 0 64 48" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g>
   <fill-code>
 </g>
 </symbol>

</svg>
```

and below is how my HTML looks like:

```
<svg class="my-svg-cta">    
 <use xlink:href="https://<external-domain>/allIcons.svg#my-svg-cta"></use>
</svg>
```

If I use the file internally it works fine but when hosted externally Icon doesnt render on any of the browsers (Chrome/FF).

Comment: There's maybe already an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32850536/cross-domain-svg-sprite
My best guess is that this is a CORS issue.

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in your browser's dev tools console?